# what is from_email used in django.core.mail.send_email used for

Tags: python, django, email

I am sending email with django and I have everything in settings.py. I have a contact form and when the `form.is_valid()` returns true I send an email from the email specified in settings to an email set in the view (experimental version). But I have also made a field in the form for the sender to leave his email as in this example [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#form-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#form-object)
But this example also uses this email in the `send_email()` function. When I receive the email I see that it was sent from the email set in settings, the subject and the message part are set correctly, I just can't see where sender variable that went in `send_mail()` is used. This means that I actually lose information who send me the email, if I do not append this string to the message or subject string... Could anyone please explain what is sender variable in `send_mail()` used for?

thanks for your help, Peter

Answer (score 1):

The `from` field is required in email headers

Here is an example of a full email header:

```
Return-Path: 
X-SpamCatcher-Score: 1 [X]
Received: from [xx.xx.xx.xx] (HELO example.com)
Message-ID: <>
Date: 
From: 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.0.1) Gecko/20020823 Netscape/7.0
X-Accept-Language: en-us, en
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: 
Subject: blah blah
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

You can readup more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Header_fields)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the form's submitter's email adress if they supply it and you are using your own email as a **from** email, of course you will have to append it to the message text that **YOU** receive. If you want the submitter to receive a copy of their message, just mail them a different version. So essentially have one version for the site maintainer and another one for the form submitter.

Hope that covers the question, I had to guess a bit.